# Handle location url in ReverseProxy

Tags: reactjs, apache

I want to put a reverse proxy (apache httpd) in order to serve my reactJS application.

Here my httpd configuration

```
ProxyPass /test/ http://example.com
ProxyPassReverse  /test/ http://example.com
```

but, in react app, i have this warning and my application is not working

```
Warning: [react-router] Location "/test/" did not match any routes
```

I think that this error is generated because when the proxy redirect the requests, he send the request to the test page.

So how can i resolve this problem in proxy side ?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I think it's a React Router issue. You might want to [change the `basename` of your `Router` component to `'/test'`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string).

Comment: Yes, if i change the basename, it will work fine, but i don't understand why the proxy httpd redirect the requests to http://example.com/test/ ?

Comment: I'm not very good at httpd, but it seems like [`ProxyPass` just specifies what backend to send the request to, but doesn't rewrite the path](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html). "In the above, any requests which start with the /images path with be proxied to the specified backend, otherwise it will be handled locally."

Comment: So ProxyPass should redirect my requests to example.com not example.com/test/